# Rails 3.1.0 conditional validations on nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-attributes

I have a structure where an `Item` may belong to a `Claim`, and if it does, I want another of its fields to be required as well. These are the relevant code snippets:

```
class Claim
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
  validates_associated :items
end

class Item
  belongs_to :claim
  validates :amount_paid, :presence => {:if => :claim}
end
```

And this works in *almost* every case. When I edit an *existing* `Claim` and try to enter blanks in the `amount_paid` field, I get the errors I want. And the `Claim` should exist when it hits this validation, because a previous iteration, which also worked, had the equivalent of

```
validates :claim_id, :presence => {:unless => :new_claim?}
...
def new_claim?
  claim.new_record? # would have thrown an error if claim was nil
end
```

But when I create a *new* `Claim` with blank `amount_paid` fields on its `Items`, the validations pass, which they shouldn't.

To no avail, I have also tried

```
validates :amount_paid, :presence => {:if => :claim_exists?}
...
def claim_exists?
  !!claim
end
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: An `Item` can also be accessed via its other parent, `Plan`, which is always required; but that isn't relevant to my question.

Comment: Your `claim` validation kicks off the `item` validations, which then only validate the presence of `amount_paid` if an associated `claim` for said item exists.  I wonder if no `claim` has been associated to the items yet since the `claim` hasn't been validated?  What happens if you write your own custom validators, one that hooks into `:if => :claim` and one that hooks into `:unless => :claim`?  See which validation, if any, gets called.

Comment: I've been playing in the console and it seems Item.claim might be nil after all:

`c = Claim.new(:items_attributes => [{:id => 1}, {:id => 2}]) #=> #<Claim id: nil>`
`i = c.items.first #=> #<Item id: 1, claim_id: nil>`
`i.claim #=> nil`

Sorry I can't put line breaks in...

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is possibly a bit of a hack, but it seems to work:

```
class Item
  ...
  validates :amount_paid, :presence => {:if => :claimed?}
  ...
  def claimed?
    !!claim || caller.any? { |m| m =~ /claims_controller/ }
  end
end
```

So if the claim exists, or if this is being called from `ClaimsController` at any point in the stack trace, the validation will run.

I'd still welcome input from anyone who has a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem can be fixed by adding an `:inverse_of` option to the associations:

```
class Claim
  has_many :items, :inverse_of => :claim
end

class Item
  belongs_to :claim, :inverse_of => :items
end
```

(It's been a while since I came across this, though, so if you're having the same problem as I was, do a bit of experimentation.)